# Is it possible to rename a tkinter widget after it has been created?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So for example:

```
import tkinter as tk

canv = tk.Canvas()
canv.configure(name="my_canv")
```

So that `canv.winfo_name()` would return `"my_canv"`

Even better would be a `tag` function like it is available for Canvas drawings so I can group multiple Canvases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

> the name option can only be set when the widget is created.

source: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm